# Unit testing respository with in MVVM pattern android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-mvvm

I am trying to write unit tests for repository while using MVVM pattern in android.

What i have is a repository which fetched data from the network using retrofit

```
   public class ValidateCbuRepository {

    private static ValidateCbuRepository single_instance = null;

    private MutableLiveData<CBUValidationImageResponse> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public static ValidateCbuRepository getInstance() {
        if (single_instance == null)
            single_instance = new ValidateCbuRepository();

        return single_instance;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<CBUValidationImageResponse> processImage(String encodedString) {

        JsonObject postParam = new JsonObject();
        postParam.addProperty("image", encodedString);

        Api service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(Api.class);
        data.setValue(null);

        HttpUrl httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse("some url");
        Call<CBUValidationImageResponse> responseCall = service.getProcessedImage_cbu_validation(httpUrl.toString(),postParam);
        responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<CBUValidationImageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CBUValidationImageResponse> call, Response<CBUValidationImageResponse> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    CBUValidationImageResponse res = response.body();
                    CBUValidationImageResponse cbuValidationImageResponse = res;
                    Log.i("CBU response ",""+cbuValidationImageResponse.toString());
                    cbuValidationImageResponse.setSuccess(true);
                    cbuValidationImageResponse.setShowProgres(false);
                    cbuValidationImageResponse.setError(false);
                    data.setValue(cbuValidationImageResponse);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CBUValidationImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                CBUValidationImageResponse cbuValidationImageResponse = new CBUValidationImageResponse();
                cbuValidationImageResponse.setError(true);
                cbuValidationImageResponse.setShowProgres(false);
                data.setValue(cbuValidationImageResponse);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
}
```

The unit test part

```
 @Mock
    private Observer<CBUValidationImageResponse> observer;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }


    @Test
    public void testApiResponse_success() {
        Api mockedApiInterface = Mockito.mock(Api.class);
        Call<CBUValidationImageResponse> mockedCall = Mockito.mock(Call.class);

        Mockito.when(mockedApiInterface.getProcessedImage_cbu_validation(any(),any())).thenReturn(mockedCall);
        try {
            Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
                @Override
                public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    Callback<CBUValidationImageResponse> callback = invocation.getArgument(0);

                    CBUValidationImageResponse cbuValidationImageResponse = new CBUValidationImageResponse();
                    cbuValidationImageResponse.setCBU_code("some code");
                    cbuValidationImageResponse.setHeight(7);
                    cbuValidationImageResponse.setBreadth(7);
                    cbuValidationImageResponse.setLength(7);

                    callback.onResponse(mockedCall, Response.success(cbuValidationImageResponse));
                    // or callback.onResponse(mockedCall, Response.error(404. ...);
                    // or callback.onFailure(mockedCall, new IOException());
                    return null;
                }
            }).when(mockedCall).enqueue(any(Callback.class));

            ValidateCbuRepository validateCbuRepository = new  ValidateCbuRepository();
            String encodedString= "";
            validateCbuRepository.processImage(encodedString).observeForever(observer);
```

Getting a null pointer exception at `validateCbuRepository.processImage(encodedString).observeForever(observer)`. Next step is to verify the observer.

I expect the test to pass. What am i doing wrong here?. I did something similar foe view model and the test passes with 100% code coverage.

The retrofit call is asynchronous. Is that the reason why it fails?

Edit : It seems livedata is null while testing causing NPE.

Comment: in your unit test you seem to miss this rule : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/core/executor/testing/InstantTaskExecutorRule

Comment: @estn that fixed the issue for NPE. but while testing observer onChanged value is null

Comment: ok lets try another thing - move that mock observer subscription to @Before

Comment: Should livedata instance be inside your repository ?